# Post error: Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

Any post in my Asp.net MVC generate this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[InvalidOperationException: Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream.]   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() +12673515   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream() +61   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +132   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory) +28   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +248   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +165   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +536   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +343   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +57   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +81   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +153   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +839919   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag) +27   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +50   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +827009   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +27   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +401   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +787114   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +27   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12622419   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18213
```

### Full error details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream.

System.InvalidOperationException: Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream.
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()
   at System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_InputStream()
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.ValueProviderFactory_GetValueProvider.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.CastleInvocationToAlternateMethodContextAdapter.Proceed()
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensions.AlternateMethodContextExtensions.TryProceedWithTimer(IAlternateMethodContext context, TimerResult& timerResult)
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context)
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.ValueProviderFactoryProxy.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

## Route config:

### Default

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "CreditoImobiliarioBB.Web.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

### Areas

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Usuario_default"
        ,"usuario/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
        ,new { controller="home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        , namespaces: new string[] { "CreditoImobiliarioBB.Web.Areas.Usuario.Controllers" }
    );
}

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        name: "Relatorios",
        url: "{controller}/{id}/relatorio/{action}",
        defaults: new { id = 1 },
        constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" },
        namespaces: new string[] { "CreditoImobiliarioBB.Web.Areas.Relatorios" }
    );
}
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        name: "Documentos",
        url: "{controller}/{id}/documento/{action}",
        defaults: null,
        constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" }
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you using any of the listed properties during routing, e.g. in a custom routing constraint?

Comment: OK, so not... :-) Does it happen if Glimpse is disabled?

Comment: @JimmiTh What properties are you talking about? Follows the routes config in my app.

Comment: Yes, actually glimpse was deployed precisely because of this problem. Already occurred before you even install the glimpse

Comment: the properties the exception lists - it refers to something early in the request handling accessing the `BinaryRead`, `Form`, `Files`, or `InputStream` of the `Request`.

Comment: understood. Very strange because it always worked. I'm trying to figure out what change might have caused this error but can only remember the OData / webapi.

Comment: And the error occurs in any post request ..

Comment: No other httpHandlers or httpModules? Web.Config might help someone who's had more experience with this error than I. :-) (Because I'm out of ideas).

Comment: @JimmiTh see all web.config in [this link](https://gist.github.com/Ridermansb/250ab74c055a3dfa313d)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33425/discussion-between-ridermansb-and-jimmith)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just posting the findings here - as a summary of the chat - since others may get this error. Don't hand out bounty, since I didn't actually find the solution. ;-)

The error itself is a result of trying to access `BinaryRead`, `Form`, `Files` or `InputStream` after something else has already accessed the request entity body stream (in other words, the content of the request) using a different method.

These "different methods" seem to include `GetBufferedInputStream` and `GetBufferlessInputStream`. These methods *appear* (not sure) to all be mutually exclusive. In other words, for a single request, you can only use one of:

- `BinaryRead()`, `Form`, `Files`, `InputStream` (these will "cooperate" with each other),
- `GetBufferedInputStream()`, or
- `GetBufferlessInputStream()`

`GetBufferedInputStream` *should* cooperate with the "classic" access methods, [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.getbufferedinputstream.aspx) - in fact, that's its only difference from `GetBufferlessInputStream`. Nonetheless, in this case, the error stems from `GetBufferedInputStream()` being used, followed by `InputStream`.

The different methods are (inadequately) described in the documentation for the [ReadEntityBodyMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.readentitybodymode.aspx) and [its enum type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.readentitybodymode.aspx).

A [recent commit](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/0678d3e314c08403e1c9584cd08846b045ad5f5f) to the ASP.NET WebAPI changed its method of reading the body entity to `GetBufferedInputStream()` where before it used `request.InputStream`.

This appears to conflict with MVC's `JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject` which uses the "classic" `InputStream` property to read the entity body. If we take the error message at face value, `GetBufferedInputStream()` has already been called, but it isn't done reading when `InputStream` is accessed, so `InputStream` hasn't been filled yet.

Need to do more testing, but a temporary fix (found by @KiranChalla) is to revert to a build from before the above-mentioned commit.

Answer (score 10):

We've reverted to using request.InputStream in Web API due to this problem ([commit 9c76bb9090490541a453fcead75485ea50b88022](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/9c76bb9090490541a453fcead75485ea50b88022)).

JimmiTh's answer correctly notes a discrepancy between the initial release notes and the implementation. As implied in the [later documentation mentioned above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.readentitybodymode.aspx) (though it is not particularly clear), request.GetBufferlessInputStream(), request.GetBufferedInputStream() and request.InputStream (along with Form, Files, etc.) are three mutually exclusive methods of request body access.

It appears that, contrary to the [initial release notes](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/whats-new/whats-new-in-aspnet-45-and-visual-web-developer-11-developer-preview), request.GetBufferedInputStream() is not currently usable unless no other callers for the same request use any of InputStream, Form, Files, etc. I'm also following up to see if something better can be done compatibility between these two methods.

David

An update after talking with the product team:
Calling request.GetBufferedInputStream() or request.GetBufferlessInputStream() means "I'm handling the stream explicitly myself; take me into advanced mode where automatic stream processing is disabled." However, in the case of buffered only, the members that normally rely on automatic stream processing (Form, Files, InputStream, etc.) are re-enabled after the buffered stream has been fully read.

So, as the exception message hints, touching any of those properties before finishing reading the stream will fail:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Request.GetBufferedInputStream();
    var ignore = Request.InputStream;
    return View();
}
```

But doing so after finishing reading the stream will succeed:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var stream = Request.GetBufferedInputStream();
    new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
    var ignore = Request.InputStream;
    return View();
}
```

The documentation isn't particularly clear here; I'll ask the product team if they can improve it.

We're planning on switching back to GetBufferedInputStream in Web API; we'll just make sure it plays better with MVC in terms of when this call happens relative to consuming the stream and MVC executing.

Comment: Thanks for the update, David - glad I wasn't *completely* off - haven't looked much at the Http implementation, and the documentation in this case is confusing, to say the least. :-)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when uploading files via Web API. Apparently *"maximum request length exceeded"* was hiding beneath this error, so increasing [maxRequestLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668155/how-do-i-resolve-the-maximum-request-length-exceeded-exception) in web.config solved it in my case.

Comment: This is a very good hint. I was seeing this error _periodically_, and checking the HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH header indicates this is what's happening. Choice!

Answer (score 6):

Today I learned that if you are using WebApi and your stream is a `System.Net.Http.StreamContent.ReadOnlyStream` and you try and read 0 bytes from it (stream.Read(buffer, 0, 0)), it will throw a `System.InvalidOperationException`, which when caught in a try/catch will show up as an exception with the message "Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream."

I realize this seems silly, but you can do the same thing on a memory stream or file stream and no exception is thrown and in my case it was coming from MsgPackCli, hopefully this saves someone 4 hours.

Comment: This is what my problem was, too. All I had to do to get around it was check to see if `HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength > 0` before reading `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream`.