# Multipart POST error: Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

From my MVC app I am trying to do a POST request to my Web API app. After receiving the data inside Web API app, when I try to read it like `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["SenderAddress"];` I get an error saying `Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream.` Below is the code for both sending and receiving:

POST request (from MVC):

```
var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var uri = _domain + "/api/email/send";

//adding all properties to the form
if (model.SenderAddress != "" && model.SenderAddress != null)
    form.Add(new StringContent(model.SenderAddress), "SenderAddress");  
if (model.Recipients.FirstOrDefault() != null)
{
    foreach (var recipient in model.Recipients)
        form.Add(new StringContent(recipient), "Recipients");
}  
if (model.Attachments.FirstOrDefault() != null)
{
    foreach (var attachment in model.Attachments)
    {
        byte[] fileData = null;
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(attachment.InputStream))
        {
            fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(attachment.ContentLength);
        }
        form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(fileData, 0, fileData.Length), "Attachments", attachment.FileName);
    }
}  
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, form);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Receiving data (at Web API):

```
var temp3 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["SenderAddress"];
```

Here I get that error. How do I solve it?

Comment: Maybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602845/post-error-either-binaryread-form-files-or-inputstream-was-accessed-before-t?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Hossein Ya I read that too but unfortunately I didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand what this has to do with end of multipart stream but here is the working code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // This illustrates how to get the file names.
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

also checked the tutorial code in asp.net site as well:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2