# upload audio file with angularjs with the implementation of upload image throws error

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I'm trying to make implementation with angularjs of upload audio file to my app
and I'm getting error.

```
Maximum request length exceeded.
```

actually I tried to use with another code of the last programmer, I had in my code of upload image that works, but this one not works.

this is my view page-audiofiles.html

```
<div class="page-content" style="padding:10%">

<div class="content-block">
    <a href="#" class="button button-fill button-big" style="background-color:#2E7695;margin-bottom:30px;" ngf-select="uploadAudio(CaseAudio.AudioFile)"  ng-model="CaseAudio.AudioFile" ngf-validate="{size: { max:'20mb', min:'10B'} }" ngf-pattern="'.mp3,.wmv'" accept=".mp3,.wmv" >Upload a audio file</a>
     <!--<a href="#" class="button button-fill button-big" style="background-color:#2E7695;margin-bottom:30px;" ngf-select="uploadAudio(CaseAudio.AudioFile)"  ng-model="CaseAudio.AudioFile" ngf-validate="{size: { max:'20mb', min:'10B'} }" >Upload a audio file</a> -->

    <!--<button style="width:100%;background-color:#2E7695;" class="button button-big button-fill button-primary" ngf-select="uploadAudio(CaseAudio.file)" ngf-validate="{size: { max:'20mb', min:'10B'} }" ngf-pattern="'.mp3,.wmv'" accept=".mp3,.wmv"> Upload a audio file </button>-->
        Audio preview:  {{ CaseAudio.AudioFile.name }} <br />

        <audio controls ngf-src="CaseAudio.AudioFile" style="width:100%"></audio>
</div>
```

javascript

```
    /* =========================================== */
/*    8.1 Audio Files                            */
/* =========================================== */

pagesModule.directive('pageAudiofiles', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'sam_app/components/pages/mea/casefiles/audio/page-audiofiles.html',
        controller: pageAudiofiles,
        controllerAs: 'pageAudiofilesCtrl',
    }
});

function pageAudiofiles($scope) {
    $SAM.InitObjects($scope);
    $scope.CaseAudio = {
        ngfBlobUrl: '',
        AudioFile: '',
        AudioFilePath: '',
    }

    $scope.caseAudios = [];
    $scope.enableDelete = false;

    $scope.uploadAudio = function(audioFile){

        if(audioFile){
            console.log("the audio is "+ audioFile);


            /*if (!audioFile.$ngfBlobUrl) {
                $SAM.notification.showNotification("Error", "error", "You can upload here only audio files.");
                return;
            }
            */
            // print details
            debugger
            //save file in server
            $SAM.services.uploadFile(audioFile, uploadProgress, uploadComplete, "POST", $SAM.services.WS.UploadCaseFileImage);
            $scope.caseAudios.push({ ngfBlobUrl: audioFile.$ngfBlobUrl, AudioFilePath: '', uploadedDate: $SAM.miscUtils.ConvertCSdateToJSdate(new Date().getTime()), progress: 0, error: '' });



        }
    }



    function uploadProgress(evt, file) {

        $scope.$apply(function () {

            //$scope.CaseAudio = $.grep($scope.caseAudios, function (v) { return v.ngfBlobUrl === file.$ngfBlobUrl; })[0];
            //show the progress bar on the correct block image
            debugger
            console.log("caseAudio: " + $scope.CaseAudio);
            var str = JSON.stringify($scope.CaseAudio);
            console.log("CaseAudio object: " + str);
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                $scope.CaseAudio.progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
            } else {
                $scope.CaseAudio.error = 'Upload Error ' + 'unable to compute';
            }
        })
    }

    function uploadComplete(evt, file) {

        $scope.$apply(function () {
            //get the correct block case image object
            $scope.CaseAudio = $.grep($scope.caseAudios, function (v) { return v.ngfBlobUrl === file.$ngfBlobUrl; })[0];

            //set the virtual path
            var data = JSON.parse(evt.target.response);

            if (data.Status == $SAM.ResponseStatus.ErrorMessage) {
                $scope.CaseAudio.error = data.Message;
            }

            else {
                //hide the progress bar 
                $scope.CaseAudio.progress = false;

                $scope.CaseAudio.picFilePath = data.Message;
            }
        })
    }







}
```

uploadFile function

```
   $SAM.services.uploadFile = function (file, uploadProgress_callback, uploadComplete_callback, method, url) {

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("uploadedFile", file);
        fd.append("caseID", $SAM.MEACase.caseID);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            uploadProgress_callback(evt, file);
        }, false);

        xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) {
            var data = JSON.parse(evt.target.response);
            if (data.EXEPTION) {
                $SAM.services.scope.$apply(function () {
                    $SAM.miscUtils.showLoadingSpinner = false;
                    $SAM.exception.constructor(data.EXEPTION);
                    $SAM.exception.PopupException = 'in';
                });
            }
            else {
                uploadComplete_callback(evt, file);
            }
        }, false);

        xhr.addEventListener("error", function (evt) {

            $SAM.services.scope.$apply(function () {
                $SAM.miscUtils.showLoadingSpinner = false;
                var data = JSON.parse(evt.target.response);
                $SAM.exception.constructor(data.EXEPTION);
                $SAM.exception.PopupException = 'in';
            });
        }, false);

        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.send(fd);
    }

    $SAM.services.log = $log;
    $SAM.services.q = $q;
    $SAM.services.scope = $scope;
    $SAM.services.timeout = $timeout;
}
```

webservice we build that works for image

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[Secure(UserPermissions.Standart)]
public void UploadCaseFileImage()
{
   // string n = "781";
    try
    {

        SAMFile samfile = new SAMFile(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0], BelongEntitys.CaseImages, HttpContext.Current.Request["caseID"]);
        //SAMFile samfile = new SAMFile(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0], BelongEntitys.CaseImages, n);
        if (samfile.UserID == ManagersGateway.User.PKID)
        {
            string virtualPath = CaseModule.UploadImageFileToCase(samfile);
            Context.Response.Write(HTTPResponseBuilder.Build(HTTPResponseStatus.OK, virtualPath));
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e is CustomException) ExceptionMessage.ThrowExeptionToResponse(e as CustomException, true);
        else ExceptionMessage.ThrowExeptionToResponse(e.Message, Resources.ServerError, ErrorCode.CD1032, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: why is this tagged with C#?

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve the "maximum request length exceeded" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668155/how-do-i-resolve-the-maximum-request-length-exceeded-exception)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum request length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Comment: I edited my post and add the webservice in c#

Comment: what you post, not really the same issue i have.